# Configuring a C++ project in Visual Studio to use the latest toolkit installed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am developing the same code on two different machines, with different versions of VS installed, and I have to reconfigure my projects each time I switch from one to the other. Is it possible to make project configurations dynamic, so the latest version of the Visual C++ Toolkit installed is used?

I looked online but did not find anything.

Comment: Use cmake, use generated vs projects, they will use the latest toolchains, and don't use visual studio created projects.

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping for a VS only solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452145/how-to-set-platformtoolset-property-from-msbuild

Comment: Is your problem solved? What C++ project did you create and did you use CMake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS version and the corresponding toolkit:

1. VS2022 V143
2. VS2019 V142
3. ...

Try using $(DefaultPlatformToolset) in Platform ToolSet.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for! (and sorry for answering so late)